# How to Parse an AT command response and one among the fields from the output in C

Tags: c, parsing, at-command, openwrt

Im trying to capture the data from the AT command response but im unable to do so.

My Approach.

functions():

```
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH (8 * 1024)
static char buf[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
static char buf2[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

static bool tr_lf_cr(const char *s)
 {
    char *p;
    p = strchr(s, '\n');
    if (p == NULL || p[1] != '\0') {
        return false;
    }
    *p = '\r';
    return true;
}

static void strip_cr(char *s)
{
    char *from, *to;
    from = to = s;
    while (*from != '\0') {
        if (*from == '\r') {
            from++;
            continue;
        }
        *to++ = *from++;
    }
    *to = '\0';
}

#define STARTS_WITH(a, b) ( strncmp((a), (b), strlen(b)) == 0)
```

main()

```
fd = fopen(*mp, "r+b");
    if (fd == NULL) {
        /* Could not open the port. */
        perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyUSB0\n");
    }
    char str = '\n';
    strncat(cmd, &str, 1);
    success = tr_lf_cr(cmd);
    if (! success) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid string: '%s'\n", cmd);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    int res = fputs(cmd, fd);
    if (res < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to send '%s' to modem (res = %d)\n", cmd, res);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    do {
        line = fgets(buf, (int)sizeof(buf), fd);
        if (line == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "EOF from modem\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        strcpy(buf2, line);
        strip_cr(buf2);
        char delim[] = ",";
        char *ptr = strtok(buf2, delim);
        printf("\n0++++++++++++++++++++\n");
        while (ptr != NULL) {
            printf("'%s'\n", ptr);
            ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
        printf("\n1********************\n");
    } while (STARTS_WITH(line, "OK") == 0);
```

I get the following output when i run this command **AT^HCSQ?**

```
0++++++++++++++++++++
'AT^HCSQ?
'

0++++++++++++++++++++
'^HCSQ: "WCDMA"'
'64'
'64'
'60'
'0
'

0++++++++++++++++++++
'
'

0++++++++++++++++++++
'OK

'
```

What i want to achieve is to store each value separately from the buffer like

char p = WCDMA;

int rssi = atoi[ptr];

[etc...]

Im using strtok() to achieve this but im unable to skip the empty lines i get from the response. What should i do here?

Comment: Write parser - what else you can do?

Comment: What is mp variable? Posted code is incomplete.

Comment: You are not far from the solution. You just need to issue `fgets` until you find the row containing `^HCSQ`: in the canonical read command's answer scenario it is the only line you need, Then skip `"^HCSQ: "` and proceed with your strtok solution.

Comment: In order to have an actual answer you need to clarify your needs: 1) a general solution for EVERY AT command? That would be too broad. 2) A solution for all ^HCSQ possible variants? (A little borderline, as the number of params vary according to the service type), 3) A solution for ^HCSQ only in WCDMA case?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, My goal is to get the values trailing the '"^HCSQ: "' I need to store the connection type and the params that follow the '"^HCSQ: "' command. Also to parse the response for '"^COPS: "'

Comment: Also to parse the response for '"^COPS: "' The place where im exactly stuck is how to use the 'fgets' to find '^HCSQ' in the line it reads and how to skip and store the params. Any direction to a sample code or a solution would be of much help. BTW..  variable 'mp' is the mount point of the device we want to read.